# How to apply ping-pong for TCP socket?

Tags: python, sockets

how to use ping/pong for checking the message is delivered to server or not and receive a pong after sucessfull delivery of message in the below code.

I found this code from this link
https://www.positronx.io/create-socket-server-with-multiple-clients-in-python/

```
server-side.py
import socket
from _thread import *

ServerSideSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ServerSideSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 3040
ThreadCount = 0
try:
    ServerSideSocket.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

print('Socket is listening..')
ServerSideSocket.listen(5)

def multi_threaded_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Server is working:'))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        print(data)
        response = 'Server message: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(str.encode(response))
    connection.close()

while True:
    Client, address = ServerSideSocket.accept()
    print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
    start_new_thread(multi_threaded_client, (Client, ))
    ThreadCount += 1
    print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
ServerSideSocket.close()




client-side.py
import socket

ClientMultiSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '172.0.0.1'
port = 3040
print('Waiting for connection response')
try:
    ClientMultiSocket.connect((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

res = ClientMultiSocket.recv(1024)
while True:
    Input = input('Hey there: ')
    ClientMultiSocket.send(str.encode(Input))
    res = ClientMultiSocket.recv(1024)
    print(res.decode('utf-8'))

ClientMultiSocket.close()
```

Comment: You basically state that you are confused and then dump some code. It is unclear what exactly your confusion is. Don't you understand what ping-pong is meant to be? Don't you understand what the code is doing? Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @ 
Steffen Ullrich when message is delieved from client to server, how server receives a pong. how to implement in the above dump code.

Comment: The server knows that the client has send a message since the server got it. The client knows that the server received the message since the server replied to it and the client received the reply. That's the implicit ping-pong.